# Scope of variables in circular dependent import modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, circular-dependency

This question is to understand the scope of the variables(class variables) when the modules imported are circularly dependent.

## main_.py

```
import a_

class MyClass:
    my_list = ["hello"]

    @classmethod
    def append_my_list(cls, item):
        if item not in cls.my_list:
            cls.my_list.append(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m_obj = MyClass()
    t_obj = a_.Test()
    t_obj.incr_class()
    print(MyClass.my_list)
```

## a_.py

```
class Test:
    def incr_class(self):
        from main_ import MyClass
        MyClass.append_my_list("hey")
```

My expected output was: `['hello', 'hey']`

The program returns : `['hello']`

When I debug it actually appends value `'hey'` but when the control comes back to the `main.py` file, my_list is set back to `['hello']`.

I know this is an inappropriate way of Python coding, but would like to understand theoretically what is happening in the classes when they are circularly dependent.

Any clarification/explanation would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing a py file within itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326245/importing-a-py-file-within-itself)

Comment: When you run a python file, it becomes the `__main__` module. So when you do `import main_`, you end up with 2 instances of the `main_.py` file - one named `__main__` and one named `main_`.